# Streaming of media

Tags: java, javafx, netty

I am trying to stream media from a server to a client. I was going to use RTSP, but in RTSP the client tells the server what to do.

I need to be able to control the media the client gets from the server. The Server tells the Client what music he wants to play.

Is there an other protocol I can use or an other way I can work around? Maybe I am wrong and you can still do this using RTSP. I need to use UDP, as I need to use multicasts, and I dont want to have to build my own protocol to keep the client synchronized.

If you need more infos, dont hestiate to use the comments field below!

**Edit**

This application is done in Java. I would be happy, if you could maybe tell me a mechanism that works well with Java. I am currently using the Netty library, which looks to be pretty useful (although I have not figured out how to use it yet). I don't need an answer that is based on pure network knowledge, I know how I could build a whole streaming ecosystem. I need to get this working on Java 8, without having to do the handling of the basic protocol stuff myself.

Comment: This isnt the right site for this type of question

Comment: @redFIVE I will edit my question, to make it the right site.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libjitsi](https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi) which is an open source Java audio/video library which can be used for streaming with encryption. It does not use Netty but it looks to be mature.